# Get number of revisions per user?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to to show how many times a user edited a node, as follows, so I have enabled revisions support for my content type.

- user1 (300)
- user2 (288)
- user3 (200)

The problem is that when someone creates a new node, it gets saved as revision in the node_revision table, but I don't want to count that as edit.

How can I achieve this?

This is the code I am using, so far.

```
$query = "SELECT users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS uid_1, COUNT(users.uid) AS uid, COUNT(users.uid) AS users_uid FROM users users
  INNER JOIN node_revision node_revision_users ON users.uid = node_revision_users.uid
  INNER JOIN users_roles users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
  WHERE (users.status <> '0') AND (users_roles.rid = '4') AND node_revision_users.nid IN ($sub_query)
  GROUP BY users_name, uid_1
  ORDER BY users_uid DESC ";

$result = db_select('node_revision', 'n')
  ->fields("n", array("nid"))
  ->groupBy('nid')
  ->having('count(nid) > 1')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAllKeyed(0, 0);

$sub_query = implode(",", $result); // this will show give nids which are edited ie having count more than one in node_revision 

$results = db_query($query);
foreach ($results as $res) {
  var_dump($res);
}
```

Comment: do you have a query to show?

Comment: Here is query how I am trying http://pastebin.com/Stzr3wqt

Comment: it is not possible with single query. but you need some workaround like you need to find out the number of nodes that this user has created in another query and then subtract that numbers from revisions you get in the above query

Comment: [@Shabir](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/38481/shabir-a) Thanks for your comments I am trying but not able to find exact solution ie: i am using this query to get number of nodes per user http://pastebin.com/RdcE7zgp please suggest